# Can a In-App Purchase be used to "buy answers"?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an app that allow people ask some kind of questions in IOS app, on backend side there are people (humans) that answer this questions. Obviously answers have some delay  (10 min - 1hour).
Can I use In App Purchase model (consumable items) for this?

Thanks you!!

Comment: What do you mean "can you"? I'm sure it's programmatically possible. Can you better phrase your question?

Comment: Programmatically is posible, my question is if Apple accept this, because the item is not show immediately.Server will send push notification and e-mail when answer is ready to view. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at Apple's in-app purchase guidelines that are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf).

Apple doesn't allow one to sell tangible products via in-app purchase. There are four categories of content that Apple allows for in-app purchase. They are:

- Content
- Functionality
- Services
- Subscriptions

I believe that your situation should fall under the "services" category. Because your app normally offers a Q&A system, and you're merely prioritizing their requests because they have paid for them, this should be acceptable within IAP guidelines.

The easiest way to find out if Apple accepts your IAP system is just to try and submit the app for review. If Apple rejects your app, they will tell you why, and allow you to make the necessary changes before submitting again. There is no harm in just giving it a shot.

Comment: "There is no harm in just giving it a shot"... Except, if you find out it defeats the entire point of the app. In which case your down quite a bit of $ and work. :)

Comment: That is true, I suppose. However, I don't see any reason for Apple to reject the IAP based on their guidelines, and hey, even if you implement it and Apple rejects it, at least you've learned something new which may help you any future endeavors :)

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest to decouple the purchasing step from posing the question, since, as you mention, payment and answering would not occur in sync. So it looks like we have a problem with transaction handling here. There are at least two ways to approach this.

1. Have people purchase **tokens** that they can use to buy answers. This way, your In-App purchases will have two separate *clean transactions*: your token counter will incremented exactly one line of code before you commit the transaction from the `SKPaymentQueue`. Then, the token counter will be decremented when the answer was downloaded by the app.
2. Another idea would be to show only **half of the answer** after it was received from the server and then use the In-App purchase mechanism to unhide the rest. That may be even more attractive to users because they get a sense of the quality of your answers.

A combination is also possible of course, where people use tokens that were previously purchased to reveal the rest of each answer.

Answer (score 2):

This would be no different than all of the games that let you purchase in-app tokens and related items.

Treat the answers as consumable in-app purchases. Maybe give the user one free answer with the app and then let the user purchase more answers via in-app purchase. Don't let the user submit a question unless they have credit to get an answer. You would probably need to track their credits on your servers.